# Left joined 2 tables, result looks like inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Question may be easy, but I'm quite new to SQL so here goes.

What I'm trying to accomplish:

I have `TableA` and `TableB`. `TableA` contains most of my data, however it should modify one of the columns (modified result) using data from `TableB` if there's a match on ID and date range.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT 
    t1.ID, t1.a, t1.b, t1.c, t1.d, t1.e, t1.f, t1.g, t1.h, t1.i, 
    (t1.totalcost  - (ISNULL(t2.cost, 0) * ISNULL(t2.qty,0))) AS modified_result, 
    t1.j, t1.k, t1.createdate
FROM 
    TableA as t1
LEFT JOIN 
    TableB AS t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE 
    t1.createdate BETWEEN '2018-06-19' AND '2018-06-23' 
    AND t2.createdate BETWEEN '2018-06-19' AND '2018-06-23' 
    AND t2.trans_type = 'H'
ORDER BY
    t1.createdate
```

There's like 2000+ records in `TableA` satisfying those criteria for `TableA` and only a few matching records from `TableB`. Running this query produces equal row number to `TableB` result, which for me looks like an inner join.

I probably have it wrong in my `WHERE` section, but I can't really see it.

Comment: Never use left joined table in where clause otherwise this will turn it into Inner Join

Comment: All restrictions applied on T2 have to be in the ON clause of the outer join.

Comment: @JaydipJadhav didn't know that, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about technical but I'm answer you from my experience from my work

when you filter t2 in `WHERE` clause. DBMS filter whole result after `JOIN`

if you want to keep all rows of t1 using subQuery instead t2 or move filter t2 to join condition example

**use Subquery instead T2**

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.a, t1.b, t1.c, t1.d, t1.e, t1.f, t1.g, t1.h, t1.i, 
(t1.totalcost  - (ISNULL(t2.cost, 0) * ISNULL(t2.qty,0))) as modified_result, 
t1.j, t1.k, t1.createdate
FROM TableA as t1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM TableB t2 
    WHERE t2.createdate between '2018-06-19' and '2018-06-23' and t2.trans_type = 'H'
) AS t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE t1.createdate between '2018-06-19' and '2018-06-23' 
ORDER BY t1.createdate
```

or

**move filter t2 to join condition**

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.a, t1.b, t1.c, t1.d, t1.e, t1.f, t1.g, t1.h, t1.i, 
(t1.totalcost  - (ISNULL(t2.cost, 0) * ISNULL(t2.qty,0))) as modified_result, 
t1.j, t1.k, t1.createdate
FROM TableA as t1
LEFT JOIN TableB AS t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID and t2.createdate between '2018-06-19' and '2018-06-23' and t2.trans_type = 'H'
WHERE t1.createdate between '2018-06-19' and '2018-06-23' 
ORDER BY t1.createdate
```

above code I'm didn't test

Hope it's help.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    t1.ID, t1.a, t1.b, t1.c, t1.d, t1.e, t1.f, t1.g, t1.h, t1.i, 
    (t1.totalcost  - (ISNULL(t2.cost, 0) * ISNULL(t2.qty,0))) AS modified_result, 
    t1.j, t1.k, t1.createdate
FROM 
    TableA as t1
LEFT JOIN 
    TableB AS t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID AND t2.createdate BETWEEN '2018-06-19' AND '2018-06-23' 
    AND t2.trans_type = 'H'
WHERE 
    t1.createdate BETWEEN '2018-06-19' AND '2018-06-23' 

ORDER BY
    t1.createdate
```

Answer (score 0):

here is your where condition

```
    WHERE t1.createdate between '2018-06-19' and '2018-06-23' and t2.createdate 
    between '2018-06-19' and '2018-06-23' ***and t2.trans_type = 'H'***
```

here your rows will be filtered as per trans type... Basically it is limiting the rows

Answer (score -1):

Including criteria from a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` table in the `WHERE` clause does NOT magically convert it into an `INNER JOIN`; there's no "special rule" that you have to include all criteria in the `ON` clause.

What has happened here is that your query without the `WHERE` clause will return some `NULL` values from `t2` and you then exclude these by including criteria for this alias that doesn't include `NULL` values.

If you were to rewrite your query like this then it would work as you want it to:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.a, t1.b, t1.c, t1.d, t1.e, t1.f, t1.g, t1.h, t1.i, 
(t1.totalcost  - (ISNULL(t2.cost, 0) * ISNULL(t2.qty,0))) as modified_result, 
t1.j, t1.k, t1.createdate
FROM TableA as t1
LEFT JOIN TableB AS t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE t1.createdate between '2018-06-19' and '2018-06-23' and (t2.createdate IS NULL OR t2.createdate 
between '2018-06-19' and '2018-06-23') and (t2.trans_type IS NULL OR t2.trans_type = 'H')
ORDER BY t1.createdate
```

Comment: Hey, downvote my answer all you like, it doesn't change the fact that everything I said is correct ;P